# Integrating AWS Lex Bot with Amazon Connect and with Support of two languages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I want to integrate a Lex Bot with Amazon Connect and the bot should support two languages eg, English US and French. The language selection will be based on the Selection in the get Customer input block prompted for language.
The Problem is how can I handle the situation if the customer selects French and the Bot should interact with a customer in French. I have also added the Language attribute in a set voice block.
With English its working fine but if I select french before invoking the lex bot. it gives me an error.
**Note: I have added Both of the languages (English and French)in Lex Bot with the reqired Intents.**

Thanks in Addvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing screenshots of your lex bot configs and flow it is difficult to tell what's going wrong, but there are a couple of things to check:

1. Make sure when you create the bot version you include both languages and that your alias is pointing to a version of your bot with both languages.
2. Make sure you have set the language using the Set Voice block with the Set Language Attribute checkbox checked. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/set-voice.html) for more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

To handle languages, you need to write a custom solution using the AWS SDK and various AWS services. You can use Comprehend to determine the language and use Amazon Translate to translate.

There is a similiar Java SDK use case here that will demonstrate this use case:

[Building an Amazon Lex Chatbot that engages users in multiple languages](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lex_chatbot)

Comment: You are talking about translating text, I'm pretty sure that Amjad has setup two languages in the Lex bot that already have the responses in the appropriate language. Lex can natively understand multiple languages without having to use any other services. That SDK example is interesting but ultimately completely unnecessary.